# Los ejecutables que creo con Auto Py to Exe de python los detecta como malicioso, uso windows 11

Tags: python

buenas esta simple linea de codigo "input("Hola:")" es la que compile, ya que estoy comenzando y queria probar con Auto Py to Exe en windows 11 pro con vscode pero me sale mi ativirus me lo detecta como si estuvise infectado, hice lo mismo con pyinstaller y ese no salto con error que creen que sea
virus total lo detecta como malicioso, me di cuenta que con auto py el ejecutable creado es de solo 1.5mb mientras que con py installer es de 7.5mb

gracias de antemano no quise ni ejecutar el ejecutable
[image: lo que muestra virus total]

Comment: Este es solo mi punto de vista, ni he escudriñado el código de AutoPyToExe ni soy colaborador ni nada... Auto Py to Exe simplemente es una interfaz gráfica junto a algunas cosa con el fin de  facilitar la vida para PyInstaller. Es [un proyecto open-source](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe)  con años de antigüedad, 3.5k estrellas en github, 600 forks... aunque no sea una garantía total ciertamente no es lo mismo que descargarte un ejecutable compilado de una pagina aleatoria... Ademas que PyPi mismo y auditores externos rastrean paquetes con fines maliciosos subidos a el.

Comment: Si quisieran infectar tu PC no hay necesidad de inyectar código malicioso en el ejecutable, ya has ejecutado el propio paquete de Python... En cambio, y es una opinión  con ciertos fundamentos...,  parte de los antivirus comerciales y ya no digo de los "gratuitos" de hoy   son mas malware que los virus que supuestamente detectan, muchos son spyware descarados o focos de vulnerabilidades en si mismos... En cuanto al tamaño, Auto Py realiza ciertas automatizaciones y optimizaciones por ti  que podrían justificarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero digo algo porque virus total lo detecta como virus aparte se que es la interfaz grafica pero porque por linea de consola me genera el ejecutable mas pequeño que la interfaz de autopytoexe ademas con uno no da alerta mi antivirus y con el otro si

Comment: Fijate que virus total parece hacer el analisis usando varios antivirus, por lo que no es virus total de por si que lo ve como virus. Y solo 7 de los 69 antivirus lo notaron como virus, así que preguntale a avast y otros, incluso a los creadores de pyinstaller. Sobre las diferencias, es posible que tenga relación con que la configuración en autopytoexe no concuerde con pyinstaller en la linea de comandos. Finalmente, cuando haces que el exe se compile en un solo archivo, todos los archivos que hubieran estado sueltos, se guardan en el exe, haciendo que pese más.

Comment: Para saber la causa de la diferencia de tamaño , como comenta Dante, habría que saber con que parámetros invoca autopytoexe a Pyinstaller vs como lo invocabas tu manualmente. Creo que autopytoexe informa del comando que se va a usar para genera el exe con pyinstaller, si no lo has hecho ya crea el exe con ese mismo comando usando pyinstaller manualmente y desde la misma instalación/entorno de virtual de python en ambos casos (pyinstaller a veces incluye paquetes instalados incluso aunque no los use tu programa, incrementando el tamaño del ejecutable), a ver si hay diferencias.

Comment: Por cierto, es bastante común que los antivirus tengan falsos positivos con ejecutables generados con Pyinstaller por varias razones, son ejecutables sueltos sin instalador de por medio, sin firmar, no es raro que se distribuyan por ahí malware usando Python + freezing (y los antivirus ven patrones similares a malware conocido), etc. Por cierto, si usas la opción onefile hay mas posibilidades de que algún antivirus te  lo detecte (no dices si en tu caso ambos ejecutables se crean con esta opción). Nuitka suele generar menos falsos positivos que Pyinstaller al generar código C y luego compilar.

Comment: gracias fsevilla me aclaraste mis dudas como dije soy nuevo en esto de la programacion en python la ultima vez que programe fue con dbase y clipper saca la cuenta jaja pero mil gracias aparte use niukita pero no soporta la version de python 3.12